# Python - Check Box Status Program

Tags: python, pdf, checkbox

I'm trying to make a program that scans PDFs downloaded from a website with selectable text and highlights specific discrepancies. I can make it work for specific "bad words" and "good words" but I am stuck on how to make it find missing check boxes. They are no longer interactive fields in PDF form:

[image]

Here is my code for everything else so far:

```
import os

import fitz

source_folder = r"C:\Users\Sserb\Desktop\Test Files"
list_files = os.listdir(source_folder)

good_terms = ["trend", "decrease", "increase"]
bad_terms = ["school", "academic", "homework"]  # words that should be in every pdf file (not every page)

pdf_files = [x for x in list_files if x.endswith(".pdf")]

highlight_summary = []

good_term_summary = []

for file_name in pdf_files:
    # READ IN PDF
    full_filename = os.path.join(source_folder, file_name)
    doc = fitz.open(full_filename)

    good_terms_not_found = good_terms.copy()

    list_hl_pages = []
    for page_num, page in enumerate(doc, 1):

        # SEARCH
        for text in bad_terms:
            text_instances = page.search_for(text)

            # HIGHLIGHT
            for inst in text_instances:
                highlight = page.addHighlightAnnot(inst)
                highlight.update()
                if page_num not in list_hl_pages:
                    list_hl_pages.append(page_num)

        # Search for good terms- all must be found
        words_found = []
        for good_word in good_terms_not_found:
            text_instances = page.search_for(good_word)
            if text_instances:
                words_found.append(good_word)

        for word in words_found:
            good_terms_not_found.remove(word)

    highlight_summary.append([file_name, list_hl_pages.copy()])
    if good_terms_not_found:
        good_term_summary.append([file_name, good_terms_not_found.copy()])

    # OUTPUT
    if list_hl_pages:
        out_file = file_name.replace(".pdf", "-errors.pdf")
        doc.save(os.path.join(source_folder, "output", out_file), garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
    else:
        doc.close()

#print(highlight_summary)
print(good_term_summary)
output_folder=r"C:\Users\Sserb\Desktop\Test Files\output"
new = os.path.join(output_folder,'outputfile.txt')
file = open(new, 'w')
value = str(good_term_summary) + '\n'
file.write(value)
file.close()
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `page.search_for()` method failed to find the words: 'BCBA', 'Behavior', 'therapist', 'Client', 'Parent', 'Sibling' in your PDF? Probably it makes sense to share this particular PDF. It doesn't seem like a common problem, it's rather a problem with these particular PDFs and their inner structure.

Comment: @YuriKhristich I could add those terms to my search - I can't put an entire PDF up here - it has private medical information on it. Is there a way to add to my words list "CHECKED BOX BCBA", where CHECKED BOX is a way to recognize the box is checked vs empty?

Comment: @K J The PDFS do not come from me - they are downloaded from a website where the boxes were checked by the creators prior to saving them. the boxes are selectable text on the pdf (I can highlight them with my cursor just like the normal text) - Is there a way to find out how to search for the checked vs empty box?

Comment: @KJ You solved my problem - Thank you so much! I'm new to this forum - how can i "upvote" you (or whatever the equivalent is)

Answer (score 0):

Both "value" and "export value" are always treated as text, but there are at least 8 different kinds of check-boxes in word. see how these are altered by the font used here Check boxes are shown as ☐ when unchecked, or ☑ or ☒ when checked, so search for ☑Client rather than ☐Client etc

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.